# running template app on ipod touch 2nd gen, nothing happens

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I'm trying to test my phonegap app on my ipod touch 2nd gen. I have the latest xcode on lion 10.7.1. There were no errors when I ran the code and even the console(in the organizer) showed nothing. Even though xcode says that the code built successfully and ran, it doesn't show up on my ipod at all.

My ipod is provisioned and I also ran the code directed to the ipod, not to a simulator.

What could this mean?

Is the ipod outdated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**note:** This answer assumes you will be able to run your app on an iPod touch. If you are using a resource not available on an iPod touch, like GPS for example, you may be being prevented from running your app by a GPS device requirement(see required device capabilities).

This sounds like a classic example of trying to run on an iPod touch 1st or 2nd gen without jumping through the apple imposed hoops. (Says finished running but never runs, logs are just spinning indicators.)

To build for these older devices, you must jump through these hoops:

How to add support for `iOS 4.2`, `armv6` in `Xcode 4.2` and up:

Set your deployment target to 4.2 or earlier:
[image]
Modify Architectures to include `armv6` like so:
1)Select Other,
[image]
2) Click on the "+" button,
[image]
3) Type in "armv6",
[image]
4) Click done.

Then remove armv7 from required device capabilities by clicking the "-" button in that row.

[image]
I personally use this method constantly to run apps on my iPod touch 2nd gen with the newest Xcode.

In fact the project that I used for this example now runs on that iPod.

Comment: thanks for the helpful answer! I couldnt find the required device capabilities in info however...